# After tokenizing a column, get 2 words before and after a specific word

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just tokenized a column in a dataframe using nltk.word_tokenize.
This column now looks like

```
df.tokenized
> 0     [apple, hi, dog, boy, why...]
> 1     [table, hey, girl, cat, dog, 2, 3...
```

For each row, I need to get 2 words before and 2 words after the word "dog". I want to put it all in another column in the same dataframe. The output I expect is something like:

```
df.tokenized_part2
> 0     [apple, hi, dog, boy, why]
> 1     [girl, cat, dog, 2, 3]
```

So I need to create this column tokenized_part2.

If you need this info:
tokenized  -  object

Does someone know how to do that?

Comment: maybe you should iterate every row and search position in row and then get `[pos-2:pos+2]`

Comment: what if there is no dog on the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply()` to run function on every cell in column and this function may get position of `dog` on list and return `[pos-2:pos+3]`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
"tokenized": [
    ['apple', 'hi', 'dog', 'boy', 'why', 'other'],
    ['table', 'hey', 'girl', 'cat', 'dog', '2', '3'],
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
]
})

def process(words):
    #print(words)
    if 'dog' in words:
        pos = words.index('dog')
        return words[pos-2:pos+3]
    else:
        #return words
        return []

df["tokenized_2"] = df["tokenized"].apply(process)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
                            tokenized                 tokenized_2
0   [apple, hi, dog, boy, why, other]  [apple, hi, dog, boy, why]
1  [table, hey, girl, cat, dog, 2, 3]      [girl, cat, dog, 2, 3]
2                           [A, B, C]                          []
```

---

**EDIT:**

To make it more universal it could get `dog` (or other word) as parameter and then you would have run it with `lambda` (or `partial`)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
"tokenized": [
    ['apple', 'hi', 'dog', 'boy', 'why', 'other'],
    ['table', 'hey', 'girl', 'cat', 'dog', '2', '3'],
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
]
})

def process(words, search):
    #print(words)
    if search in words:
        pos = words.index(search)
        return words[pos-2:pos+3]
    else:
        #return words
        return []

df["tokenized_dog"] = df["tokenized"].apply(lambda words:process(words, 'dog'))
df["tokenized_cat"] = df["tokenized"].apply(lambda words:process(words, 'cat'))

print(df[["tokenized_dog", "tokenized_cat"]])
```

Result:

```
                tokenized_dog             tokenized_cat
0  [apple, hi, dog, boy, why]                        []
1      [girl, cat, dog, 2, 3]  [hey, girl, cat, dog, 2]
2                          []                        []
```

Comment: Perfect!
To make it even more universal: 

list_words = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird']

for item in list_words:
    df['col'+ '_' +str(item)] = df["tokenized"].apply(lambda words:process(words, item))

Answer (score -2):

One way to do it is using apply with lambda like

```
lambda x: [i for ix,i in enumerate(x) if ix in range([idx for idx,it in x if it=='dog'][0]-2,[idx for idx,it in x if it=='dog'][0]+2)]
```

But it's computationally expensive, error prone, and probably needlessly complex.

Comment: this is totally unreadable or understandable

Comment: @gold_cy it's literally `process` from the other answer as a nested list comprehension inside a lambda. Or rather, since they answered after me, their function is my nested list comprehension splayed out in a needless amount of characters. 

If someone needs to explain to you that placeholders in comprehensions (like loops) and lambda expressions (like functions) don't need to be meaningful to be understandable, you should consider where the root of that issue is. 

They wanted working code. The code works.

Comment: sacrificing lines of code to make it readable is always considered the right approach. extra lines of code does not mean extra processing. in a language like Python, readability is paramount and what it excels it.

Comment: Oh. I thought it was the amazing assortment of libraries, the dynamic typing and the ability to solve a problem incredibly efficiently in code instead of having to type reams and reams of it for simple problems.

Comment: By the way, I'm going to now choose to understand your first comment programmatically instead of in a natural language sense. Thank you for saying my code is understandable @gold_cy.